# How to detect collision only in non-transparent texture?

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection, transparency

I am developing a game using `libGDX`. I am trying to detect the collision between bee and tube. I am using the following code to detect the collision.

```
if(player.getBounds().overlaps(boundsBot)){

}
```

`player` is a bee and `boundsBot` is `Rectangle` of tube. Since there is some transparency in bee image, this returns `true` even if it doesn't seem to collide. I understand the reason why this is returning true.

[image: With Transparency]

[image: Without Transparency]

I read this [solutions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/71821/76619). I understood the theoretical concept to the solve the problem but I couldn't achieve it using `libGDX`.

Here is what I tried,

```
if(Intersector.intersectRectangles(player.getBounds(), boundsBot, rectangle)) {
    //Gets the intersected rectangle
    System.out.println("Rectangle Bottom: " + rectangle);

    //Converting texture to pixmap
    Texture texture = player.getTexture().getTexture();
    if (!texture.getTextureData().isPrepared()) {
        texture.getTextureData().prepare();
    }
    Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();

    //Trying to find transparency.....  
    System.out.println("Format: "  + pixmap.getGLFormat());
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank You!

Comment: Although I have no particular experience with libgdx, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405361/libgdx-get-pixel-color-from-sprite-or-texture) has an answer that should make you able to determine the colour of a pixel. Pixel perfect collision is not easier than that, though you could try a different shape than a rectangle. I think a bounding circle, for example, would fit your shape a lot better.

Answer (score 4):

I had faced similar problem, when I was building a tower defense game.Where I needed to check for collision between tower boundary (ellipse) and enemies (rectangle),[image]

**first method :**
I have used the condition for checking if these points exist inside the ellipse like

```
if(ellipse.contains(point1X,point1Y)||ellipse.contains(point2X,point2Y)...)
{
    System.out.println("attack");
}
```

I picked those points that was in the boundary and  that will collide with boundary most often.And I had 20 to 25 enemies rendered onto  screen at same time and 3 to 5 forts checking for above condition whether any enemies are inside fort,My game was successful and had frame rate between 55fps and 60fps.

what you can do is check for condition if bee collided with the wall like

```
if(rectangle.contains(point1X,point1Y)||rectangle.contains(point2X,point2Y)...)
{
    System.out.println("bee collided with wall ");
}
```

**Second method:**
You can also solve this using another approach ie using polygons and Intersector,for this you have to plot a polygon over the bee and wall.
Like this

[image]

create  polygons for bee and also for the wall

For bee

```
float[]verticesForBee=new float[]{-20,-20, -20,20,-10,20,-10,30,10,30,10,20, 20,20, 20,-20 };
Polygon beePoly=new Polygon();
beePoly.setVertices(verticesForBee);
```

For Wall

```
float[]verticesForWall=new float[]{-10,-20, -20,20,-30,20,-300,30 };
Polygon wallPoly=new Polygon();
wallPoly.setVertices(verticesForWall);
```

Now using Intersector.overlapConvexPolygon() method check if the polygons overlap with each other

```
if(Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(beePoly, wallPoly))
{
    System.out.println("bee got collided with the wall");
}
```

Comment: I am trying this logic but I am facing the problem: since the tubes are moving, it is hard to find the vertices in every check.

Comment: The tubes can be moved using wallPoly.setposition(x,y) ,Now make your wall or tube sprite follow the wallPoly polygon for that you can use wallSprite.setPosition(wallPoly.getX(),wallPoly.getY())

Comment: You can also set orgin for your sprite as wallSprite.setOrgin(orginX,orginY)